# Show slide-out div after click of button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using simplecart.js on my site to add items to a cart. [Site can be seen here.](http://www.rubytuesdaycreative.co.uk/testsite/snood.html)

The documentation mentions use of an After Add function:

```
// basic callback example
simpleCart.bind( "afterAdd" , function( item ){
  console.log( item.get("name") + " was added to the cart!" );
});
```

I'd like to use this function in my script to make a slide out div `panel` to slide out once the item has been added.

The existing jQuery for the slide out panel is:

```
///////
///Settings object
///////
var settings = {
    objSlideTrigger: '.trigger',
    objSlidePanel: '.panel'
}
```

There is also the full jQuery in a linked file:

```
///////
///Slide out tab
///////
function slideOutTab() {
    //Bind a click handler to the trigger
    $(settings.objSlideTrigger).bind('click' , function() {
        //If the panel isn't out
        if(!$(settings.objSlidePanel).hasClass('out')){
            //Animate it to left 0px
            $(settings.objSlidePanel).animate({
                'left' : '0px'
            });
            //Add the out class
            $(settings.objSlidePanel).addClass('out');
        }
        else {
            //Otherwise, animate it back in
            $(settings.objSlidePanel).animate({
                'left' : '-330px'
            });
            //Remove the out class
            $(settings.objSlidePanel).removeClass('out');
        }
    });
}
    $(function(){slideOutTab();});
```

Plus the existing simplecart javascript.

```
simpleCart({
    checkout: {
      type: "PayPal",
      email: "hello@myemail.com",
    },
    currency: "GBP"
});
```

I understand that I need to use the basic callback example, but instead of the console message need to call the javascript for the slide out, but I'm not sure of the syntax. Can anyone help?

Comment: The specified jquery for the slide out is only for the settings, not the actual function that calls it. Can you find and post that slide out function?

Comment: The full JS was linked but I've now put it in full in the code. Just worried it was a little long.

Comment: Having seen that, the solution by @Ohgodwhy should work just fine.

Comment: I've got this working with the code below but have noticed a small fault, if the cart slideout is already open when you click, it closes it. I wonder if there is a way round this?

Answer (score 1):

You call `slideOutTab()` on DOM load, so the element has a `click handler` attached to it.

```
simpleCart.bind( "afterAdd" , function(){
    $('.trigger').click();
});
```

Comment: Should this go within simplecart script or within the slide out script? I have tried it within simpleCart script but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

To check if the cart is open or not, then open if it isn't:

```
simpleCart.bind( "afterAdd" , function(){
    if(!$(settings.objSlidePanel).hasClass('out')){
        $(settings.objSlidePanel).click();
    }
});
```

The "!" means to check if it does "not" have the class 'out.' In other words, the if statement is true if it is in, which causes the click method to fire.

Comment: Are you sure this is correct? This script brings up errors in the console but I can't work out what it is. Seems like a bracket closing error?

Comment: It was wrong. Sorry. I just made the correct adjustment. Try again.